# Where to get the source tar of zend debugger for PHP 5.3.x for linux?

Tags: php, debugging

I went [here](http://www.zend.com/en/products/studio/downloads),but the web debugger only contains the windows version  `zenddebugger.dll`, where to get the source tar of zend debugger or better the zenddebugger.so for linux?

Answer (score 0):

Try this site.  http://downloads.zend.com/pdt/server-debugger/

Comment: I went there,but no package for PHP 5.3.x

Answer (score 0):

You can get the PHP 5.3 version of the Zend Debugger from the Zend Studio download page.

http://www.zend.com/en/products/studio/downloads

It's the Studio Web Debugger, which has versions for 4.3, 4.4, 5.0, 5.1, 5.2, 5.3

You have to register for a Zend account, but you don't need to buy Zend Studio to get it.

Comment: There's only windows version...

Comment: Click the linux tab on that page.